# Replace left side text with regex in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to replace statements like these:

```
identity_LineItemId TEXT(300),
identity_TimeInterval TEXT(300),
bill_InvoiceId TEXT(300),
```

With these in a large file:

```
identity_LineItemId=NULLIF(LinkedAccountId, ''),
identity_TimeInterval=NULLIF(LinkedAccountId, ''),
bill_InvoiceId=NULLIF(LinkedAccountId, ''),
bill_BillingEntity=NULLIF(LinkedAccountId, ''),
```

I tried:

> search: .* TEXT(300)
>
> replace with: \1=NULLIF(\1, ''),

But that didn't work.

How can I use a regex replace in notepad++ to replace `TEXT(300)` with `table_name=NULLIF(table_name, ''),`  ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using regex for such a simple straightforward substitution. But if you'd really like to use regex, you should learn about substitution groups, escaping special characters and character classes at least. I recommend this to do your tests: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture the first group:

`(.*)\sTEXT\(300\)`

and replace with whatever you want using `\1` to use the first captured group again (everything up to the space)

```
\1=NULLIF\(LinkedAccountId, ''\)
```